# How to bind event for dynamically created elements in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i have created some dynamic elements using jquery and add a dropdownlist using ajax inside dynamic elements ,The problem is when i select a option from a dropdownlist,then upcoming ajax data are override the all other dynamic elements data.
 [image: See the picture]

now i want to bind data every dynamic elements data separately in jquery.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var html = $("#dsp > .row:first").first().html();
  var maxrows = 5;
  var x = 1;
  $("#addrow").click(function() {
    if (x <= maxrows) {
      $('#dsp').append(html);
      x++;
    }
  });

  $("#rmvrow").click(function() {
    $('#dsp').children().last().remove();
  });
  
    $('#dsp').on('change','.p_name',function(){
      var pid=$(this).val();
      var parent=$('#dsp');
      
      //alert(pid);
      $.ajax({
        url:"{{route('getinfo')}}",
        method:'post',
        data:{id:pid,'_token':"{{csrf_token()}}"},
        success:function(response) {  
            console.log(parent.find('.p_code').val(response.code));
  
        }
      });

    });
});
```

```html
           <div id="dsp">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <select name="p_name[]" class="form-control p_name">
      <option value="">-Select Product-</option>
      @foreach($products as $product)
      <option value="{{$product->product_id}}">{{$product->name}}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" name="p_code[]" class="form-control p_code">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" name="unit_pctn[]" class="form-control unit_pctn" readonly="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" name="u_price[]" class="form-control u_price" readonly="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <input type="text" name="ctn[]" class="form-control ctn">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <input type="text" name="pcs[]" class="form-control pcs">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" name="t_amt[]" class="form-control t_amt">
    </div>

  </div><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep giving dynamic id for each of your rows and use that to add listeners.

On every add row call a funtion that does

```
function addrow(rownumber) {
    document.getElementById('dsp' + rownumber).addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        // do some action
    });
}
```

Comment: He's already using jQuery delegation, why should he change to this style?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's Jquery or javascript. He can still add listener dynamically both ways. I just gave one possible solution. I guess his question was  

" How to bind event for dynamically created elements in JQuery "

Comment: Did you read the question and understand the problem he's having? How does your answer solve the problem that when he does the AJAX call it fills in the response in all the rows?

Answer (score 0):

Your code for delegating event binding is fine. The problem is that your second `success` function doesn't put the response in the current row, it fills in all `.u_price` fields. Change that to:

```
parent.find(".u_price").val(response.client_price);
```

When you add a new row, it needs to be inside its own `<div class="row">`, so that `$(this).closest(".row")` will select the correct row. You currently just have one `class="row"` and it's the `#dsp` DIV that contains all the rows. Each row needs to be a child of `#dsp`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var html = $("#dsp > row:first").first().html();
  var maxrows = 5;
  var x = 1;
  $("#addrow").click(function() {
    if (x <= maxrows) {
      $('#dsp').append(html);
      x++;
    }
  });

  $("#rmvrow").click(function() {
    $('#dsp').children().last().remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="dsp">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <select name="p_name[]" class="form-control p_name">
      <option value="">-Select Product-</option>
      @foreach($products as $product)
      <option value="{{$product->product_id}}">{{$product->name}}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" name="p_code[]" class="form-control p_code">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" name="unit_pctn[]" class="form-control unit_pctn" readonly="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" name="u_price[]" class="form-control u_price" readonly="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <input type="text" name="ctn[]" class="form-control ctn">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <input type="text" name="pcs[]" class="form-control pcs">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" name="t_amt[]" class="form-control t_amt">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's show the product code, but i can't bind it separately pcode field.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "bind it separately pcode field".

Comment: Does it show the `client_price`? If not, there's a problem with your `getprice` API, it's not returning the desired information.

Comment: when i select product name from dropdown list , it's fetch the product code by an ajax request.problem is i cannot assign product code for separately because last selected product code override the other field product code. please see this picture: https://i.imgur.com/9DXq0T2.png

Comment: My answer only fixes the problem with the product price. It looks like you're already doing it correctly for `.p_code` and `.unit_pctn`.

Comment: Do you have multiple `<div class="row" id="dsp">`? IDs need to be unique.

Comment: no, there have only id dsp. i'm try this line after ajax success:  console.log(parent.find('#p_code')); in console show this message: [prevObject: m.fn.init(11), context: document, selector: ".form-control #p_code"]

Comment: Your image shows two rows of input fields. Aren't they both `<div class="row" id="dsp">`? If not, what does the second row look like?

Comment: It should be `parent.find(".p_code")`. You need to search for a class, not an ID.

Comment: You also shouldn't repeat `id="p_code"` in each row.

Comment: now i'm try this code,  var parent=$('#dsp'); after ajax success: console.log(parent.find('.p_code')); now show message in console: [input.form-control.p_code, prevObject: m.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: "#dsp .p_code"]

Comment: Could you edit the question and show what the HTML looks like for two rows?

Comment: after first row then every row append from this variable:                         var html='<div class="col-md-2"><select name="p_name[]" class="form-control p_name"> <option value="">-Select Product-</option> @foreach($products as $product) <option value="{{$product->product_id}}">{{$product->name}}</option> @endforeach </select></div><div class="col-md-2"> <input type="text" name="p_code[]" class="form-control p_code"> </div></div>';

Comment: still overriding happen, i update my question please see.

Comment: Don't remove the original code from the question. How will anyone understand what my answer was fixxing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.bind data working this way and calcuate total also work.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dsp').on('change','.p_name',function(){
      var pid=$(this).val();
      var parent= $(this).closest('.row');
      //alert(pid);
      $.ajax({
        url:"{{route('getinfo')}}",
        method:'post',
        data:{id:pid,'_token':"{{csrf_token()}}"},
        success:function(response) {   

          //alert(response.code);
          parent.find('.p_code').val(response.code);
          parent.find('.unit_pctn').val(response.pcs_per_ctn);
        }
      });

        $.ajax({
        url:"{{route('getprice')}}",
        method:'post',
        data:{id:pid,'_token':"{{csrf_token()}}"},
        success:function(response) {
          //alert(response.code);

          parent.find('.u_price').val(response.client_price);

        }
      });



    });

    //calculation here

    $('#dsp').on('input','.ctn',function(){
         var cal=$(this).val();
         var gparent=$(this).closest('.row');
         var unitp=gparent.find('.u_price').val();
         var unitpctn=gparent.find('.unit_pctn').val();
         var pcs=gparent.find('.pcs').val();
        //alert(pcs);
        var total=(((parseInt(unitpctn)*parseInt(cal)) + parseInt(pcs))*parseInt(unitp));

           gparent.find('.t_amt').val(total);

           //grand total
           var gtotal=0;
           var gtotal=parseInt(gtotal)+parseInt(total)
           //alert(gtotal);
           $('#tot').val(gtotal);


    });

     $('#dsp').on('input','.pcs',function(){
         var pcs=$(this).val();
         var gparent=$(this).closest('.row');
         var unitp=gparent.find('.u_price').val();
         var unitpctn=gparent.find('.unit_pctn').val();
         var ctn=gparent.find('.ctn').val();
        //alert(pcs);
        var total=(((parseInt(unitpctn)*parseInt(ctn)) + parseInt(pcs))*parseInt(unitp));

           gparent.find('.t_amt').val(total);

           //grand total

           var gtotal=0;
           $('.t_amt').each(function(){ gtotal += parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0; $('#tot').val(gtotal); }); 
         });

  });
```